# How to remove dangling cursors in Android?

Tags: android, crash, android-cursor

How to remove dangling cursors in Android? I am closing the database whenever my work with cursors is completed.

I want this as I am getting the same error as showed in [Google Issue Tracker issue 36921069](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36921069).

Comment: you need to paste some code... and point to the line that gives the exception

Comment: exception is in the link given in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me how to remove dangling cursors

Call `close()` on the Cursor object when you no longer need it (e.g., `onDestroy()` of the activity using it).

> I am Closing the Database whenever my work is completed with cursors.

That has nothing to do with closing the cursors.